# location of a button/textfield in a view in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nstextfield

I'm sorry to ask such a question, but I can't seem to find the answer for it from the wild web.

I want to find out the location of a `NSTextField` in my custom view, so I can add other textfields under it programmatically. 
The reason I don't just add other textfields in IB, is because I need to be able to dynamically create them.
The `NSTextField` is linked to an `IBOutlet`.

So the main question is: **How do I find out the location of a `NSTextField`** (or `NSButton`, it doesn't really matter atm) **in a custom view** (I need to get the coordinates of the item)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every kind of view or control (like `NSButton`, `NSTextField`, etc.) that inherits from `NSView` has a `-frame` method that contains the positioning information.

If your custom view has an `IBOutlet` connected up to the `NSTextField`, you could do the following:

```
NSRect textFieldFrame = [textField frame];
```

That `NSRect` contains all of the information for where the text field is positioned.

See the following 2 guides for more information:

[View Programming Guide: Understanding a View's Frame and Bounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW9)

[Cocoa Drawing Guide: Coordinate Systems and Transforms](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCIDJJBI)

Answer (score 1):

Make an instance Variable with the  NSTextField and then call these methods on it to get the four values you want.

```
NSRect textFieldFrame = [textField frame];

NSPoint textFieldLocation = textFieldFrame.origin;
NSSize textFieldSize = textFieldFrame.size;

NSInteger x = textFieldLocation.x;
NSInteger y = textFieldLocation.y;

NSInteger width = textFieldSize.width;
NSInteger height = textFieldSize.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any view has both a `bounds` and a `frame` property. `bounds` is the rectangle that encloses the view in that view's own coordinate space; `frame` is the enclosing rectangle in the superview's coordinate space. In this case, you want the text view's frame, i.e. its location and size in the view that contains it, so that you can locate other text views in the same superview.